# I can set up a Facebook page with graph api?

Tags: c, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wonder if it is possible this programmatically, what I try to do is create multiple Facebook pages in a project without having to go to www.facebook.com

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information. What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried already?

Comment: look what I want to do is a project where I have a button eg GroupA and when I press that button the automatically generated page in facebook with the name of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer: No, you cannot create Facebook Pages with the Graph API. Mostly for spam reasons, i guess.